# Schema fails to load in Pentaho BI Server 5

Tags: pentaho, mondrian

This is the single fact table I would like to model as a cube:

```
CREATE TABLE `test1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `key1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `key2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

This is the Mondrian schema (test1.xml) I came up with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Schema SYSTEM "mondrian.dtd">
<Schema metamodelVersion="4.0">
    <PhysicalSchema>
        <Table name="test1">
            <Key>
                <Column name="id"/>
            </Key>
        </Table>
    </PhysicalSchema>
    <Cube>
        <Dimensions>
            <Attributes name="K1" keyColumn="key1" hasHierarchy="false"/>
            <Attributes name="K2" keyColumn="key2" hasHierarchy="false"/>
        </Dimensions>
        <MeasureGroups>
            <MeasureGroup name="N" table="test1">
                <Measure name="n" column="val" aggregator="sum"/>
            </MeasureGroup>
        </MeasureGroups>
    </Cube>
</Schema>
```

Now the database is successfully accessible from BI Server.

The problem is when I try to import the new cube through the Data Source Manager where I select the XML file and the JDBC data source.

Then I get an error message:

**"Publish to Server General Error Mondrian File: test1.xml"**

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The above Mondrian schema openly states being of version 4 (Mondrian 4) and also uses features not available in version 3.x (Mondrian 3.x).

But Pentaho BI Server 5 is currently not compatible to Mondrian 4 and shipped with Mondrian 3.6.1 (see /.../biserver-ce/tomcat/webapps/pentaho/WEB-INF/lib).

So it has to fail.

Answer (score 0):

And in the case where the schema version is not specified but still output the same message error, what would be the right approach, please.
Knowing that i am just trying to overwrite an existing mondrian file.